# if z is a solution of $(z-i)^3 = i\bar z-1$ then $z=i$ or $z=i+e^{i\theta}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have this equation (E)
$$
(z-i)^3 = i\bar z-1
$$
I have solved the first question:
Prove that if z is a solution of $(E)$ distinct from $i$ then $|z-i|=1$
but I am stuck at the next question:
Conclude from previous question that if z is a solution then $z=i$ or $z=i+e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: If you put $z=i$ in the equation $LHS=RHS=0$. Also any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, with $|z|=1$, can be written as $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$(z-i)^3 = i\bar z-1 \iff (z-i)^3=i(\bar z+i)$$

that is by $w=z-i$

$$w^3=i\bar w \implies |w|^3=|w| \implies |w|(|w|^2-1)=0$$

which requires that

$$|w|=0 \implies z=i$$

or

$$|w|=1\implies w=e^{i\theta} \implies z=i+e^{i\theta}$$

Comment: I did not get how did you pass from here:$ |w|^3=|w|$  to here: $w^3=i\bar w \implies |w|^3=|w|$

Comment: $w$ needs to have modulus equal to one.

Comment: The exercise asks me later to solve $e^{4i\theta}=i$ where $\theta \in ]-\pi, \pi]  $. I solved it but after it says find then the solutions of E

Comment: @GhassenBenHamida Yes from here $w^3=i\bar w$ we obtain $w^4=iw\bar w=i|w|^2=i$ that is $e^{i4\theta}=i$, then we can also find $z$.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using the polar form $re^{i\theta}$ of a complex number, it is apparent that:

$|z-i|=1 \iff \exists \theta:z-i=e^{i\theta}$